# DJI-SDK / FollowMeMission / How to get the GPS signal of the remote controller

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to let the drone to track the GPS signal of the remote controller. My drone is Mavic 2 pro and my remote controller is C2. Here is my code. Using this code the GPS signal of the controller I get is always 0.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jij1S.png)

Answer (score 0):

The RC deosn't have a GPS. You have to do normal android gps calls.

Be aware that many devices have worse gps-reception when connected to the RC.

Are you really using C2 with the mavic2? That RC will only work with the spark.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I'd like to ask if I can remove the height limit in the mission.

Comment: You welcome! Try to be more precise when you asking questions. What mission? What height limit. If you mean the 500m max height it can't be changed. I'm not aware of any height limit for waypoint mission. Or do you mean you are in a restricted zone with a height limit? Or do you mean the max altitude gps limit?